# Bootstrap and placeholder

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

so I'm having a weird problem that I haven't encountered before.  My code is the following:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
  <h4>Send message to seller</h4>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">                
      <form action="#" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group"> 
          <label for="InputEmail">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" placeholder="Enter your email" >
        </div> 
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="InputText">Your text</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="InputText" name="message" placeholder="Type in your message" rows="5" style="margin-bottom:10px;"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
</div>
```

When I run it on the server, this is the result, and it is really annoying:

```
 <div class="form-group"> 
 <label for="InputEmail">Email address</label>
  <div class="has-placeholder form-control"><label>Enter your email</label><input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail"></div>
```

For the second code, I omitted the rest of the code.  As you can see, it adds a new  and a new  with a class of place-holer.

I have 2 versions of this file.  Full HTML, and one with PHP etc.. The HTML version is just fine, but this one, for some reason, has this result.  Can anyone explain to my why this is happening.

I have looked in the js files that are being included and cannot find anything regarding that added class and what not.

Thanks.

Comment: do you use any template engine?

Comment: Can you paste your php code here?

Comment: Maybe it is about the <input> tag is not closed properly. Try self closing with a "/>"

Answer (score 1):

Your this `html` code is just perfect. Probably you missed some tag in `php` file. Can you please post your `php` code so that we can sorted it out.

Thanks